# Beautiful Soup NoneType error

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a small script in Python to help me through some of the more tedious parts of my job. I wrote this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import os
import sys

questid = "1478"
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("Data/xmls/quests.xml"), "lxml")

for quest in soup.find_all('quest', {"id":questid}):
    print(quest)
    questSoup = BeautifulSoup(quest)
    for floor in questSoup.find_all('location_id'):
        print(floor)
```

What this is supposed to do is to get a part of a huge xml called "quests", based on tag -  and its attribute - "id". Then it is supposed to make a new soup from that part and get all the  tags from within the . For now, before I figure out which quest ids I want to choose (and how will I handle input), I just hardcoded one ("1478").

The script so far prints the quest, but fails to create a new soup from it.

Is it possible that the quest variable is not a string? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for quest in soup.find_all('quest', {"id":questid}):
    print(quest)
    # questSoup = BeautifulSoup(quest)
    for floor in quest.find_all('location_id'):
        print(floor)
```

No need to build a new `soup` object from `tag` object, you can use `find_all` on both of them, as both are navigable strings, so they behave in the same way and can be accessed in the same way.

In my opinion, `soup` object is special `tag` object which is named `document`

---

```
import requests, bs4

r =requests.get('http://www.google.com')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
soup.name
```

out:

```
'[document]'
```